# Cascading tile layers?

Tags: leaflet, wms, getmap

I am getting data (GetMap) from a very slow WMS service. As I need to render the tiles very fast on devices, I was thinking to run a nightly batch on my server which grabs all the tiles and save them locally, in order to supply them faster during the day with LeafletJs.

Now it comes the question: is an installation of a full GeoServer the only option for this?

Comment: You can use standalone GeoWebCache or MapCache or MapProxy or some other tile proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) is a good robust solution using Java but you could also use [mapproxy](https://mapproxy.org/) (python) or [mapcache](http://mapserver.org/mapcache/) (C).

In any case, you probably only want to seed the cache down to a limited depth (roughly where you think all users will view) and then let users seed as they zoom further in. Also be kind to the remote server and only refresh the tiles that have changed each night.

Answer (score 2):

WMS is NOT the way to go for Mobile Devices. You can transform a WMS into mbtiles or geopackage SQLite Raster Tiles for use on Mobile Devices.  This is something that can be done from GIS Client like QGIS Desktop with QTiles Plugin or Global Mapper.  If you want to preserve the ability to have getfeatureinfo requests then I recommend building a geopackage of that vector source data. You can also try Proxying the WMS as XYZ Tile Server so instead of one getmaprequest, it breaks it up into zoom levels and column and row (256x256) Tiles. As someone suggested you could also use MapProxy to transform your WMS into mbtiles, geopackage or folder of tiles TMS/XYZ.